# Representing Locales as Integers not as Alpha2-Code

Tags: localization, locale

I am looking for a way to represent Languages as integers not as in Alpha-2-Code "de", "fr" and so on. Any standards (ISO, IEEE) available?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes ? There are numeric and alphabetic notations. PS: before asking, you may need to take some time tom research the answer (this site and Wikipedia are good starting points)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the standard you shared is the territorial representation of countries. This obviously creates problems, when addressing countries with multiple spoken languages like Switzerland, Belgium, South Africa etc.

Comment: You get a similar table about languages. And then you combine. Locales are not so standardized (there is much more then just country and language, e.g. you can choose old or new writing style of German, style, encoding of text, etc. If you read the RFC you see that the string could go very very long (but nobody is able to implement all features). Just put an own ID to your supported locales